# Align font awesome icon baseline in flex container

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a heading with two badges with some information about the sections. One of them contains a font awesome icon, causing the `align-items: baseline;` of that whole badge to fail: the badge is a few pixels lower than it should be. If I move the icon to the end of the badge or if I place something in front of it (like `&nbsp;`), the problem resolves, but the icon needs to be the first thing in the badge. Wrapping it in a `div` does not work. See the snippet for the live example.

Why does Font-awesome (or rather the `<i>` tag) not comply with `align-items: baseline;` like the rest of the tag? How can this be resolved in css?

```css
h3 {
  align-items: baseline !important;
  display: flex !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.badge {
  font-size: 1.125rem !important;
  line-height: 1.75rem !important;
  padding-left: 0.75rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.75rem !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0.125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.125rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(252 210 143 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(119 48 0 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  margin-left: .5rem !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3 class="d-flex tw-items-baseline">
  Flights
  <span class="badge">
    29
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    <i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-right: .5rem !important;"></i>3:28
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    3:28<i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-left: .5rem;"></i>
  </span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:inline-block` to select the `last baseline` instead of first from icon.

OR

Why don't you just align them in center ? Also if I possible avoid ussing `!important`

```css
h3 {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.badge {
  font-size: 1.125rem !important;
  line-height: 1.75rem !important;
  padding-left: 0.75rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.75rem !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0.125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.125rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(252 210 143 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(119 48 0 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  margin-left: .5rem !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3 class="d-flex tw-items-baseline">
  Flights
  <span class="badge">
    29
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    <i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-right: .5rem !important;"></i>3:28
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    3:28<i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-left: .5rem;"></i>
  </span>
</h3>
```

Comment: I think he is trying to align everything to baseline of `Flights` word.  That is why not using center.

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome icons are actually characters(text) with special glyphs. The issue is happening because of the difference in font sizes. The icons(characters) have `13.5px` and the brown text has `18px` font size. Although they look same size but the font sizes are different.
If you put icons, with small size, first then their baseline gets aligned with parent containers baseline. And rest of the brown text is centered as per the .badge CSS rule.
You can fix it like this:

```css
h3 {
  align-items: baseline !important;
  display: flex !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.badge {
  font-size: 1.125rem !important;
  line-height: 1.75rem !important;
  padding-left: 0.75rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.75rem !important;
  align-items: baseline !important; /* <-- change */
  border-radius: 9999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0.125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.125rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(252 210 143 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(119 48 0 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  margin-left: .5rem !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
}

.badge > i {  /* <--- new rule */
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3 class="d-flex tw-items-baseline">
  Flights
  <span class="badge">
    29
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    <i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-right: .5rem !important;"></i>3:28
  </span>
  <span class="badge">
    3:28<i class="fas fa-stopwatch fa-xs" style="margin-left: .5rem;"></i>
  </span>
</h3>
```

I've made only two changes:

```css
.badge {
  ...
  align-items: baseline !important;
}

.badge > i {
  align-self: center;
}
```